# Is there a difference in usage between 賃銀 and 賃金?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, kanji-choice

I was looking into a novel and I found the word 賃銀. According to my dictionary, this word has the same meaning as 賃金, which is *wages*, the money a person receive for a work/task.

They have the same pronunciation and 賃銀 is another form of 賃金 (according to [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%B3%83%E9%87%91)). But what I still don't know is in which case 賃銀 is used over 賃金.

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/賃銀　explains the kanji as written in other forms.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that ! But unfortunately, it doesn't tell in which case the other forms appear.

Comment: Usage and context may play a role. Please wait for an answer.

Comment: According to the Wiki on 賃金, while 賃銀 was oft used in the past, from 1950 賃金 became the standard. Not an answer, as I'm not sure to what extend that standard is currently observed.

Comment: Can you provide the wiki link ?

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B3%83%E9%87%91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this site, [戦前は「俸給{ほうきゅう}」もしくは「賃銀{ちんぎん}」で、戦後は「賃金{ちんぎん}」に](http://tingin.jp/kaisetsu/04.html)

「俸給{ほうきゅう}」

> ホワイトカラーが受け取るものは「俸給{ほうきゅう}」と呼ばれていました。

The salary white collar worker received called 「俸給{ほうきゅう}」.

「賃金{ちんぎん}」（「賃銀{ちんぎん}」とも書く）

> ブルーカラーが受け取るものは「賃金{ちんぎん}」と呼ばれていました。

The salary blue collar worker received called 「賃金{ちんぎん}」.

The sample expression from old novel,

> *「三度目に掛合つた老車夫が、やつとの事でお豊の望む**賃銀**[ちんぎん]で小梅行きを承知した」（『すみだ川{がわ}』永井荷風{ながいかふう}）*

`Third Old-Rickshaw driver we had negotiated finally approved to go to Koume with salary Otoyo afforded.`

`Sumida-River, Sumidagawa by Kafū Nagai.`

So, the salary written as 賃銀{ちんぎん} was payed for physical work before.